# Loop true object names displaying different name if alarm is true?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a function populateNames(), that loops true all the names in jsonObjects.
In jsonObjects I have a value(alarm), that is true or false.
Know I wanna be able to display all the names from jsonObjects, and if a jsonObjects name alarm is true output the name in red, and if the jsonObjects name alarm is false output the name in green.

```
function populateNames() {

    for(i = 0; i < jsonObjects.length; i++) {

        if(availableNames.indexOf(jsonObjects[i].name) < 0) {

            availableNames.push(jsonObjects[i].name);
            $("#chan").append('<li><a href="#">' + jsonObjects[i].name + '</a></li>');
        }
    }
}
```

In the if statement bellow Im testing something like this:

```
if(jsonObjects[i].alarm == true) {

    $("#chan").html('<li><a href="#"></a></li>');
}
else {

    $("#chan").html('<li><a href="#"></a></li>');
}
```

Comment: you haven't added the name for displaying in the anchor tag in if condition?

Comment: @DeepakBhattarai Hi, I know. But if I put name in the anchor tag if condition is not resolving my problem... If you have any idea how to solve it, please give me a hint.

Comment: I guess you have got the answer below

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
function populateNames() {
            var color = "green";
            for (i = 0; i < jsonObjects.length; i++) {
                if (jsonObjects[i].alarm == true) {
                    color = "red";
                }
                else {
                    color = "green";
                }
                if (availableNames.indexOf(jsonObjects[i].name) < 0) {
                    availableNames.push(jsonObjects[i].name);

                    $("#chan").append('<li><a style:"color=' + color + ';" href="#">' + jsonObjects[i].name + '</a></li>');
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Nice code, Its not working, but im working on your code to make it work. The html code is displaying right div style='color' but its not displaying any color...

Comment: Your code is working know, but I changed style="color=' + color + ';" to style:"color=' + color + ';".

Answer (score 0):

If alarm property would be an object or string your condition will still return true, so it would be better to modify it as follows:

```
jsonObjects[i].alarm.toString() == "true"
```

As for color, you can do something like this:

```
$("#chan").html('<li><a href="#" style="color: '+ (jsonObjects[i].alarm.toString() == "true")? "#FF0000" : "#00FF00" +'"></a></li>');
```